# perform computation inside struct or interface?

Tags: struct, interface, go

I am constructing a Data to save to mongodb. I have a json response from an API like this

```
{
  coord: { lon: 20, lat: 30 }
  main:
      [
        {"temp":304.15,"pressure":1005,"humidity":74,"temp_min":304.15,"temp_max":304.15}
      ]
}
```

inside main[0].temp, main[0].temp_min, main[0].temp_max values are in kelvin. I want to convert it to do conversions to celsius before saving it mongodb.

I can make a simple struct like this:

```
type Item struct {
  Temp string
  Pressure int
  Humidity int
  Temp_min string
  Temp_max string
}
```

but I want to do a conversion in Temp, Temp_min & Temp_max before saving it.. Is there other way rather than assigning it to variable, then reassigning?. can this be done in an Interface?

Im still not fluent in Go, but I am studying, while building a webapp in Go.

Comment: Modifying deserialized objects is a bad practice because the object may be corrupted. You should rebuild the new object to be serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you initialize your structure?

If you have access to it's values, you can convert it during structure initialization, something like this:

```
func NewItem() *Item {
    return &Item{convertToCelsius(temp), pressure, humidity convertToCelsius(tempMin), convertToCelsius(tempMax)}
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion!, I can access its values, and I tried doing what you have suggestion and I guess this looks good to me. this way I can have a setter function. thank you!